# Is there an isomorphism of fields between $\mathbb{F}_{3^{2}}$ and $\mathbb{F}=\{a+bi; a,b \in \mathbb{F}_{3}\}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, field-theory, finite-fields

if $\mathbb{F}=\{a+bi; a,b \in \mathbb{F}_{3}\}$ where $i=\sqrt{2}=\sqrt{-1}$ and we define $(a+bi)+(c+di):=(a+c)+(b+d)i$ and $(a+bi)\ast (c+di):=(ac-bd)+(ad+bc)i$

Is there an isomorphism of fields between $\mathbb{F}_{3^{2}} and\ \mathbb{F}$ such that:

$\phi(0_{\mathbb{F}_{3^2}})=0_{\mathbb{F}}$

$\phi(1_{\mathbb{F}_{3^2}})=1_{\mathbb{F}}$

$\phi(x+y)=\phi(x)+\phi(y)$ and

$\phi(x\ast y)=\phi(x)\ast\phi(y)$

Comment: The main question is: how do you define $\mathbb{F}_{3^2}$? If it is just a field having 9 elements, you only need to prove your ring is a field with 9 elements.

Comment: yes its just a field with 9 elements, then i just have to prove F is a field with 9 elements?

Comment: There is probably a typo in *...$i=\sqrt{2}=...$*.

Comment: If you know the theorem that says that two fields with the same number of elements are isomorphic, then you only need to proof their are fields with the same number of elements.

Comment: Thank you guys! Just another question how can i verify what it says after such that

Comment: @ItzelSilverstein I don't understand your last comment.

Comment: Sorry i mean how can i verify the last $\phi(0_{\mathbb{F}_{3^2}})=0_{\mathbb{F}}$

$\phi(1_{\mathbb{F}_{3^2}})=1_{\mathbb{F}}$

$\phi(x+y)=\phi(x)+\phi(y)$ and 

$\phi(x\ast y)=\phi(x)\ast\phi(y)$

Comment: See my answer below knowing that $p(i)=0$.

Comment: Thank you! Now i see

Answer (score 0):

The polynomial $p(x)=x^2+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb F_3[x]$. Hence $\mathbb F \cong \mathbb F_3[x]/(p)$ is a field with 9 elements. Therefore isomorphic to $\mathbb F_{3^2}$ (as finite fields are unique up to isomophism).